# OpenLayers 3 Print Example

Tags: openlayers

This example http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/export-map.html on OpenLayers 3 does not work if you add more than two layers. I'm reading my layers from MapServer and the error is **Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.** Can you assist

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, your local drive is declared to be "other-domain" and will taint the canvas.

(That's because your most sensitive info is likely on your local drive!).

While testing try these workarounds:

- Put all page related files (.html, .jpg, .js, .css, etc) on your desktop (not in sub-folders).
- Post your images to a site that supports cross-domain sharing (like dropbox.com).  Be sure you put your images in dropbox's public folder and also set the cross origin flag when downloading the image (var img=new Image(); img.crossOrigin="anonymous" ...)
- Install a webserver on your development computer (IIS and PHP web servers both have free editions that work nicely on a local computer).